# How to force msbuild and nuget to pack the referenced Lib as dll?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have 2 Projects:
Project A is .Net Standard 2.0
Project B is .Net Framework 4.6.1

In B I reference to A like this (csproj):

```
 <ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="A.csproj">
  <Project>{60DEB41B-8670-4199-95C2-FE68EB06B099}</Project>
  <Name>A</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Now when I pack a nuget of B, I can't access A because it doesnt resolve the dependency.

here are the commands, run by gitlab ci, to create the project B:

nuget restore
msbuild B.csproj
nuget pack -version $VERSION
dotnet nuget push **/*.nupkg ...

How to include the lib of A as DLL in B?

Comment: Have you tried adding `-IncludeReferencedProjects` option to `nuget pack` ?

Comment: Hi PassionateDeveloper, any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Actually**, adding a reference at the project level does not automatically add the corresponding reference dll during the packaging process. You need to add an additional `dll` to the nuget package manually.

I have two solutions:

**Solution One**

**Just** as `Cem.S` said, use `-IncludeReferencedProjects` to pack your project.

Also, since you pack a net framework nuget project, you only have to [use nuget.exe cli to pack the project with the created nuspec file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package):

Use this command to pack your project B:

```
nuget pack xxx\B.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

**Solution two**

**Or** just add such node in `B.nuspec` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>xxx</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <authors>xxx</authors>
    .....
  </metadata>
  <files>
   <file src="xxx\xxx\A.dll" target="lib\net461" />
  <files>
</package>
```

**Then**, run `nuget pack xxx\B.csproj` to generate the new version.

**Before** you install the new version, you should [first clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders).

Answer (score 0):

The `TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage` target will also accomplish this. [See the reference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#targetsfortfmspecificcontentinpackage) for an example.